# Keynesian vs classical consumption functions

Tags: macroeconomics, keynesian-economics, classical-economics

I am new to studying Economics and am at a loss of intuition to understand the difference between the Classical and Keynesian systems.

The following is my understanding of the two theories:

The Classical theorists came up with the implicit theory of aggregate demand where they believed that interest rate will ensure that changes in autonomous components of demand ($C$, $I$ or $G$) are offset against one another. For instance, if $I$ increases, interest rate will increase and consumption will go down by exactly the same amount by which $I$ increases in the end once the market equilibrates (because the reduced consumption will now become the savings to feed the requisite increase in $I$) . The Keynesians, on the other hand, proclaim that when $I$ increases, it will lead to an "income-induced" increase in $C$ and in totality, the total income $Y$ will change. Interest rates will still increase in the Keynesian world, because with increases in $Y$, the speculative demand for money has to change (and interest rate ($r$ have to go up) to ensure money market equilibrium.

These two approaches seem to be coming to very different conclusions. The former says that whatever happens, $r$ will ensure that $Y$ remains constant, while the other one says that increases in autonomous factors such as $I$ will not be offset by increase in $r$ and the total $Y$ will go up. I guess that this is happening because Keynesian theorists believe that demand for money also depends on interest rate $r$ as against Classical practitioners who believed that money demand only depended on $Y$.

However, I believe that there is still something that I am missing.
I am trying to find the one thing that will explain the key difference between the two approaches. Can anyone please help me understand that key difference between the two theories which allows for complete offsetting of $C$, $I$ and $G$ against one another due to $r$ in one but not the other?

EDIT: I just finished studying the IS-LM Model and the following is my understanding: When one of the factors, say $G$ increases, as per the simple Keynesian system, $Y$ should have gone up by $G*1/(1-b)$, but that doesn't happen because as $Y$ changes, interest rate changes (due to increase in transactional money demand). This change in interest rate will reduce $I$ but at the same time, due to increases in $r$, the speculative demand for money would decrease. All in all, the change in $Y$ would be somewhat less than $G*1/(1-b)$. In Classical model, there is no room for speculative demand and hence there is only one value of $Y$ where money demand can equate money supply and hence everything has to offset to come at that level. Is my understanding correct?